# how can I animate an API function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have this code that uses an API supplied by a plugin (wordpress)

```
$('#my_overlay').click(function(){
        uberMenu_close('#menu-item-1459');
        return false;
    });
```

What it does is it closes the sub-menu associated with #menu-item-1459 when the #my_overlay is clicked.
However it is really abrupt since there is no animation.

How can I add an animation effect to the code above?

Here is the JS that defines the API of "uberMenu_close('ID')" (just in case I have to actually edit this instead of my code above, and to give you a better picture)

```
function uberMenu_close( id ){
    var $uber = $ujq('#megaMenu').data( 'uberMenu' );
    $uber.close( id );
}
```

Thanks

Comment: we would need to know the code for the .close function as it seems to be the one doing the actual closing.

Comment: you mean the $uber.close?? I'm hunting it down in the code now. One sec, if that's not what you mean let me know! Thanks!

Comment: Agreed with @PatrickEvans. If it's just adding and removing a class, you could potentially do the animation with CSS transitioning on the `#menu-item-1459` element (or, more preferably, on all menu items).

Comment: I can't find anything else that has to do with the .close?   Should I be looking in the same JS file or is a tossup to what file it may be in? Also could it be in a php file?

Comment: I'd try using fadeOut(), and then in the callback doing the official close call.

Comment: Hey @Seano666 Do you mind posting the answer with the code formatted in the way you described? Sorry, I'm not sure how to code that   Thanks

Comment: No problem, there you go man.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try changing the second function you posted to add fadeOut() functionality.  Something like this.

```
function uberMenu_close( id ){
    var $uber = $ujq('#megaMenu').data( 'uberMenu' );
    //adjust how quickly you want it to fade, 1000 is one second
    $(id).fadeOut(1000,function(){
        $uber.close( id );
    }); 
}
```